# What are the consequences of ignoring non-physical solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

1. a particle in a finite width  1 - D quantum well, produces 2 math solutions outside the well walls ( $e^{bx}$ and $e^{-bx}$,( ignoring normalising factors.)
2. The decaying function, $e^{-bx}$, is used because it agrees with our physical experimental results, as it demonstates a prob. of <= 1 that the particle willl be found somewhere within in the finite wall or within the well.
3. The increasing function, exp ~(bx) is not used as it creates problems with normalisation of probabilities. We (mostly) just ignore it ( as with many awkward maths answers)

Is my belief, that UNTIL the conflict between what the maths is telling us, and that which experimental evidence is telling us, is resolved,  it will prevent any reconciliation  beween  between Q. M and G. R. at high energies /mass correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conflict. When you get additional "wrong" solutions is because you have not completely characterized the system you want to describe, or neglected some other mathematical constraint of the physical theory you are using.

In this case you want to describe a particle confined in a box, so you are looking for a solution decaying at infinity and the $e^{bx}$ solution does not do that.
Additionally, one of the basic axioms of quantum mechanics is that the physical solutions *must have finite norm*, and again the $e^{bx}$ solution does not satisfy that criterion.

Comment: Moreover, if you assume one of the non-physical solutions and compute the normalization for it you find that the multiplier approaches zero as let the range of the integration approach infinity, so it fixes itself.

Comment: @dmckee I'm not sure I understand. Isn't that like saying: "I've got a solution with infinite norm, so to normalize it I multiply it by a constant which must then be zero for the product to have finite norm."? Do you mean it as a way to show that the constraint of quantum mechanics imposing the solutions to have finite norm simply imposes the non-physical solutions to be zero?

Comment: Hmm ... yes, that was very unclear and yes, your version is what I meant.

Comment: Got this question from QM for Dummies, good for simple basic examples  but from memory he does use the word "discard" wich is incorrect for the same reason given above for my question. So takehome is a. think first before asking and b. don't trust single sources, esp a book with almost infinite number of typos  - edited very badly, if at all